# Polymer data binding between 2 elements breaks after adding 1 value to Array when using localstorage

Tags: html, data-binding, polymer, local-storage

I have 2 elements that both display an Array on screen using `<template is="dom repeat">`. They're different because 1 of them also uses a filter in the template. When I press a button to add another object to the Array (which is stored locally using `<app-localstorage-document>`, both elements will update. However, if I add another object to the Array, only the element will update where I'm calling the function. Here is the code of how I'm trying to achieve the wanted result:

Element 1:

```html
<app-localstorage-document key="tables" data="{{tables}}"></app-localstorage-document>

<paper-button raised on-click="addTableClickHandler" id="add">add table</paper-button>
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tables}}" as="table">
  <paper-card><div>Table [[table.number]]: [[table.status]]</div></paper-card>
</template>
```

Element 2:

```html
<app-localstorage-document key="tables" data="{{tables}}"></app-localstorage-document>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tables}}" filter="isFree" as="table">
    <paper-card><div>Table [[table.number]]</div></paper-card><br>
</template><br>
```

Both elements have an empty tables Array as a property:

```html
tables: {
     type: Array,
     value: []
}
```

When I refresh the page, both elements will display the correct values, but I need it to update immediately.

Both elements share the same parent element, but I don't do anything else relevant in the parent element.

I either need to make sure the data binding doesn't break after the first time I press the "add table" paper-button. Or I need to figure out a way to have the template in Element 2 update/refresh every time the addTableClickHandler function is called in Element 1. I did a bit of research to find out how to do this, but I didn't manage to fix it. Anyone any ideas?

EDIT: I've now added a delete button in element 2 to delete objects from the array and whenever I use that, the list in element 1 DOES update correctly. It's only the other way around that doesn't work. So when I add an object, the list in in element 2 will update just once and after that no more.

Comment: Data binding in polymer is strange but mostlikely the error is in JS please post the add and delete function

Comment: @PascalL. there was no error sadly.